# Does the size of a black hole change depending on its charge or spin?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, charge

I was talking to this friend of mine who said that the size of a black hole could vary depending on its "charge" and spin. He said the size of a black hole would reduce if it had a spin or charge. The size of a black hole 35*solar mass would be around 105 km, but he said that if it had a spin or charge, it would reduce, to about 51 km. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A charged black hole is described by the [Kerr-Newman metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric). This has two event horizons at radial distances given by:

$$ r_\pm = \tfrac{1}{2}\left( r_s \pm \sqrt{r_s^2 - 4r_J^2 - 4r_Q^2} \right) $$

where:

$$\begin{align}
r_s &= \frac{2GM}{c^2} \\
r_J &= \frac{J}{Mc} \\
r_Q &= \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0c^4}
\end{align}$$

For $J=Q=0$ the outer horizon is obviously just that of a normal nonrotating uncharged black hole, and the inner horizon is at $r=0$. As you increase the angular momentum $J$ and/or charge $Q$ the outer horizon moves inwards and the inner horizon grows outwards until at $r_s^2 = 4r_J^2 + 4r_Q^2$ the two horizons meet at $\tfrac{1}{2}r_s$.

So assuming that by *size* you mean the position of the event horizon then your friend is correct and a black hole will shrink, down to half its original size, as you add spin or charge.

Comment: Is this electromagnetic charge? How does a black hole acquire charge?

Comment: @Amphibio: yes, $Q$ is just the charge in coulombs. The black hole could be charged because the matter it formed from was charged, or you could take an uncharged black hole and fire charged particles into it. However in practice it's exceedingly unlikely any macroscopic black hole carries a significant charge as there is no known mechanism for generating such large charge separations.